# JPA Stop Executing Code in Transaction if Exception Occurs

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA transaction like the following (Using controller advice to catch exceptions)

```
@Transactional
public void save(MyObj myObj) {
  // Attempt to save the object
  this.myRepo.save(myObj)
  // After it saves, call my audit log service to record the change
  this.myAuditLogService.logChange(myObj)
}
```

Works fine, but the problem is if the save fails and throws an exception, it still calls the audit log service, and then throws an exception afterwards. Causing erroneous audit entries to be created.

**Expected Flow**

1. Call save function
2. Save fails
3. Transaction stops and rolls back
4. Controller advice catches the exception

**Actual Flow**

1. Call save function
2. Save fails
3. Audit log service is called
4. Transaction rolls back
5. Controller advice catches the exception

Comment: Is `myAuditLogService` using the same database and same transaction?

Comment: Nope different database. That method sends of a rest call to an audit log service which handles that work. If it was in the same database it would nicely roll it back. I just would have thought if an exception occured, it would immediately roll back and not continue code execution within the transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem in Computer Science in Distributed Systems.

Basically what you want to achieve is to have atomic operation across multiple systems.

Your transaction spans only your local (or first) database and that's all. 
When the REST call to the second system is initiated and successful but the first save results in crash you want to have rollback on the first system (first save) and rollback on the second system as well. There are multiple problems with that and it's really hard to have atomic-like consistency across multiple systems.

1. You could use Database supported technologies for such cases:

What you probably need is a [2PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol)  / [3PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_commit_protocol) or change the processing of your request somehow.
The trade-off of course will be that you'll have to sacrifice immediate results to have eventual consistency.

2. You could use `eventual-consistency`

For example send `message` to some storage for later processing -> make both systems read the `message`:

- System1 reads from storage this `message` and will save `myObj`
- System2 reads from storage this `message` and will log change

This will of course happen "eventually" - there will never be a guarantee that either system is up at the time of the processing or even later on (e.g. somebody killed the server or deployed code with bug and the server restarts indefinitely).

Moreover you'll sacrifice `read-after-write` consistency.

You could use in case of a failure a [Compensating transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compensating_transaction).

I recommend reading more on the topic of Distributed Systems in:

- (Fallacies of distributed computing)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing]
- (Designing Data Intensive Applications)[[https://www.amazon.com/Designing-Data-Intensive-Applications-Reliable-Maintainable/dp/1449373321]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449373321)
- (CAP theorem)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem]
- (Consistency models)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model]

Comment: This is really good information! For clarification the one part I don't get is why it kicks off the rest call after it knows the save failed. As far as I know the default behavior is not async execution. So I'd think it would wait to see the result of the save, see it fails, then begin rolling back an not execute further code in the transaction. And yeah our future state is changing away from this model, this is just a temporary fix. It was requirement that we do not store the audit log within the same database as where the data was being kept.

Comment: The `save` method is not making a request to the DB immediately. You can think of it in a way that Hibernate "accumulates" changes to your entities and when the transaction ends there is a "flush" and then the execution in the DB takes place and `commit` or `rollback` happens. So basically you don't even need to call `save` if you're in the transaction and you've changed your entities.

Comment: Ahhh. I had misunderstood the basics of how hibernate works leading me to head down the wrong path on how to build all this. Thanks for the clarification!